# How can I apply a procedure on each row of a table in PostgreSQL (not a trigger)

Tags: postgresql

let's say I have

**t1**

```
 a | b  | t2_a
---+----+------
 1 | 10 |
 2 | 11 |
 3 | 12 |
 4 | 14 |
 5 | 16 |
```

(all values in `t2_a` are null, I just add the column)

and **t2**

```
 a | b
---+----
 1 | 11
 2 | 12
 3 | 13
 4 | 16
```

I need to add a new line in **t2** when `t1.b` is not in `t2.b`, so after procedure, **t2** becomes :

```
 a | b  
---+----
 1 | 11
 2 | 12
 3 | 13
 4 | 16
 5 | 10
 6 | 14
```

and now I need to update **t1** to satisfy this condition `(t1.t2_a=t2.a AND t1.b=t2.b)`, so after the procedure **t1** becomes :

```
 a | b  | t2_a
---+----+------
 1 | 10 |   5
 2 | 11 |   1
 3 | 12 |   2
 4 | 14 |   6
 5 | 16 |   4
```

I don't need the algorithm, I just need to know what are the available PostgreSQL mechanisms to perform such an altering on every row of a table.

I thought I would make a trigger and a PostgreSQL procedure before or after an update on **t1** but I am not updating anything and I guess I can't just write `UPDATE t1` to trigger.. my trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the column `a` is serial in both tables.

The first operation is `insert ... select ...`:

```
insert into t2(b)
select b
from t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t2
    where t2.b = t1.b)
returning *;

 a | b  
---+----
 5 | 10
 6 | 14
(2 rows)
```

For the other use `update ... from ...`:

```
update t1
set t2_a = t2.a
from t2
where t1.b = t2.b
returning t1.*;

 a | b  | t2_a 
---+----+------
 1 | 10 |    5
 2 | 11 |    1
 3 | 12 |    2
 4 | 14 |    6
 5 | 16 |    4
(5 rows)
```

Comment: but then t2 is not modified.

Comment: t2 is modified in the first query and t1 in the second one.

Comment: my bad, didn't see. thakns